# setTimeout() method doesn't execute when using variables

Tags: javascript, animation, settimeout

I am trying to write a function that draws a bottom border for an element when you click it.
The function uses the element, minimum width, and maximum width as parameters.
When I use it with the setTimeout() to call itself it doesn't work.

If I use actual numbers in the setTimeout() it works fine.
I couldn't find what's the problem...

Anyone can help?

Thank you!

```
function drawBorder(elem,start_wid,end_wid)
{

//Checks if the header is in starting position.
//if it is - expend the width. If not decrease the width up to the starting
//position.
 if (elem.clientWidth <= start_wid)
  {
   increaseBorder(elem, end_wid);
  }
 else if (elem.clientWidth >= end_wid)
 {
  decreaseBorder(elem, start_wid);
 }
}


function increaseBorder(elem, end_wid)
 {
  elem.style.width=elem.clientWidth + 3 + "px";
  if (elem.clientWidth >= end_wid)
    {
     clearTimeout(timer2);
    }
  else {
    var str="increaseBorder(" + elem + ", " + end_wid + ");";            
    timer2=setTimeout(str,3);
 }
}

function decreaseBorder(elem, start_wid)
 {
  elem.style.width=elem.clientWidth - 3 + "px";
  if (elem.clientWidth <= )
   {
   clearTimeout(timer2);
   }
  else {
   var str="decreaseBorder(" + elem + ", " + start_wid + ");";
   timer2=setTimeout(str,3);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a reference to an element as a string. This

```
var str="increaseBorder(" + elem + ", " + end_wid + ");";
```

will result in something like

```
"increaseBorder([object ...], 100);"
```

as the default string representation of an object is `[object <Class>]`. It would even result in a syntax error when the string is evaluated.

**Never** pass a string to `setTimeout`. Pass a function directly:

```
function increaseBorder(elem, end_wid) {
     elem.style.width=elem.clientWidth + 3 + "px";
     if (elem.clientWidth >= end_wid) {
         clearTimeout(timer2);
     }
     else {          
         timer2 = setTimeout(function(){
             increaseBorder(elem, end_wid);
         }, 3);
     }
}
```

**Further notes:**

You should also fix your other errors, like `if (elem.clientWidth <= )` and you should always call `clearTimeout`, to also stop timeouts started from the other function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the functions `increaseBorder` and `decreaseBorder` are not declared globally. When a string it passed to `setTimeout`, it is evaluated in the global context, which appears to be the problem here. Instead of passing a string, just pass a function to setTimeout.

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    increaseBorder(elem, end_wid);
}, 3);
```